# Update html input value after saving modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to update some input with many modal (generated with php and ajax) but it's not working correctlyand im not sure if it's possible.

I use onclick event on my modal on "save changes" and I want update html value.

But html is not updating.

```js
function save(elem) {
  var modalParent=elem.closest('.modal');
  var user_login=modalParent.querySelector('.user_login');
  var user_password=modalParent.querySelector('.user_password');
  document.getElementById(modalParent.id).getElementsByClassName('user_login')[0].value=user_login.value;
  document.getElementById(modalParent.id).getElementsByClassName('user_password')[0].value=user_password.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modalID<?php echo $post->Clone;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Identifiants" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Identifiants de connexion</h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <input class="user_login" type="text" value="administrator"/>
  <input class="user_password" type="password" value="xxxxxxxxxx"/>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-blue-grey z-depth-0" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button onclick="save(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-warning z-depth-0" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't undestand well, but i guess you must clean inputs after perform save operation.

Comment: I updated my question, maybe it's more understandable.